# Why does this query produce the same information?

Tags: sql

I am using the Lyric Database. I am wondering why this query produces the same information:

```
SELECT M.LastName, A.ArtistName 
FROM members M
LEFT JOIN XRefArtistsMembers X USING(MemberID) 
JOIN Artists A on X.ArtistID = A.ArtistID;
```

And

```
SELECT M.LastName, A.ArtistName 
FROM members M 
INNER JOIN XRefArtistsMembers X USING(MemberID) 
JOIN Artists A on X.ArtistID = A.ArtistID;
```

There are no errors. I can post relevent records from the tables by request.

Comment: The first query is using LEFT JOIN the second is using INNER JOIN. May I ask the differences between the two?

Comment: maybe they produce the same results because there are no records in `XRefArtistsMembers` that do not match the left table (`members`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

INNER JOIN only chooses only those entries from the two joined tables, where the values from the fields in the JOIN clause match in both tables.

LEFT JOIN chooses all entries from the first table, combined with either the matched entries from the second table or with NULL values instead, if there was no match.

If every row from the first table had a match in the second table on the field mentioned in the JOIN clause, then both INNER JOIN and LEFT JOIN will produce the same results.